# HttpClient is not posting form data

Tags: c#, httpclient

Can anyone tell me why is the `PostAsync` of the `HttpClient` is not posting the form data?

I'm getting no data on the server side at the time of this client posting.  Last time I checked, the `formFields` contains data in key-value pairs but not able to find data in `formContent`.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var formFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    formFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AccountId", _dealerAccountId));
    formFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", _dealerUsername));
    formFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", _dealerPassword));

    var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formFields);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(httpPrefix + "://" + httpHost + "/WebApi/Token/GetToken_v1/1592673/", formContent);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return;
    }
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseContent);
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. Are you certain the data isn't getting posted and that the problem isn't with how you're receiving it on the server? Is it some flavor of ASP.NET on the back end? Could you post that and describe how you're verifying that no data is received?

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remembering having a similar issue.  We ended up not using the "PostAsync" method but used the following.  This is a helper method we use for testing our WebAPI. Hope this helps.

```
public async Task<TestHttpResponseMessage> Post(string url, string jsonPayload = "", Dictionary<string, string> headers = null, IFilter filter = null, HttpContent content = null)
{
    using (var server = CreateTestserver(filter))
    {
        if (!url.StartsWith("http"))
            url = "http://localhost/" + url;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content ?? new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        request.Headers.Add("usertoken", OpenApiApplication.TestApiKey.ToString());

        if (headers == null)
            headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var header in headers)
            request.Content.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);

        var httpResponseMessage = await server.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);

        var stringResult = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return new TestHttpResponseMessage { JsonObject = Json.Decode(stringResult), HttpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage };
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to simulate a form post. Your code posts a JSON payload and custom headers. Not sure how this helps.

Comment: Swap out the StringContent with your FormUrlEncodedContent.  I was just wanted to show you how we did get this to work but not with "PostAsync"