# C# HttpClient PostAsync won't work with django rest framework

Tags: c#, django, xamarin, django-rest-framework, httpclient

in Django (DRF)

in test.views.py

```
class TestAPIView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        return Response(request.data)
```

in test.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import TestAPIView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/$', view=TestAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

as you can see, my test url should return the post data.
and which does works well in browsable api and Unity WWW(something like httpclient which unity provides).

but it wont work with HttpClient PostAsync(or SendAsync either)

this is my C# code

in Xamarin / C#

```
    Post newPost = new Post { Title = "asdfasfa", Content = "asdfasffasf" };

    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPost);

    Debug.WriteLine(content);

    var response = await _client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/", new StringContent(content));

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
```

and the results from the console....

in C# Console

the commented string was written by me. not from the console

```
{"Id":0,"Title":"asdfasfa","Content":"asdfasffasf"} // <- this is the sent data.
Thread started:  #6
Thread started:  #16
Thread started:  #17
{} // <- and the received data
```

and...

in Django(DRF) Console

```
[26/Feb/2017 13:37:34] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
<QueryDict: {}>
```

where did my post datas gone???
django received     `<QueryDict: {}>`

and this only happens for httpclient. and maybe only with django.
i tested it with => https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
and the post creation just worked fine.

It could be a Django problem, could be a C# problem, I don't know...
help please!

ps?. HttpWebRequest just works fine too.

Comment: Are you port forwarding 8000 to your Django host as `127.0.0.1` is the localhost of the device/emulator (*assuming* this code is running on a device/emulator since you have it tagged as Xamarin)....

Comment: You need to use the IP or FQDN of your server.  Using the loopback address will connect to the DEVICE/EMULATOR that your app is running on, not the server

Comment: Check which content type you send to server. Since you use StringContent without specifying mediaType constructor parameter - I guess it will be "text\plain" but you are trying to pass json data, so that sohuld be "application\json"

Comment: it's really not about address/ emulator/ internet configuration things, because it works fine with HttpWebRequest.+ while using RestSharp i found something interesting. when i give data as json, it wont recieve, but with addparameter(balbla), works so fine.  im guessing its media type or some sord of that problem, but trying with @Evk's solution, still not working..

Comment: Then to be sure check on server side which headers you receive in request.

Comment: edited the django code, it says <<< 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' >>> + if the content type is wrong, server would return  <<< {
  "detail": "Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."
} >>>

Comment: why "/account/test/" in Django(DRF) Console side , and "/test/" in client side ?

Comment: I send the post to account/test/ but to prevent confusion, i just told you guies that its test/   === will be edited

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# at all but according to other posts ([httpclient call to webapi to post data not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560017/httpclient-call-to-webapi-to-post-data-not-working) or [HttpClient is not posting form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752165/httpclient-is-not-posting-form-data)) you probably need to set more informations in the `StringContent`:

```
StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```